# Manually open hyperlinks in specific app in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the Twitter app to follow a lot of news outlets. Each one of them posts links to articles on their websites. I want to open those articles in the news outlet's dedicated Android app. Some of them, like the NYTimes app, does it by itself. But most of them don't. I'm figuring that's because they haven't declared an intent in their app to do so. So basically I want to write an app that would give me an option to redirect the hyperlink of the article to a specific app, and I want to do it for multiple apps. Would it be possible to create a regex that would run on the URL and redirect it to the proper app accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to create a regex that would run on the URL

That is impossible to state in the abstract. Android's `<intent-filter>` system does not allow for filtering on all parts of a URL.

> and redirect it to the proper app accordingly?

That is impossible to state in the abstract:

- There is no requirement for the app for a news site to have any means for outside apps to tell it what to view
- There is no requirement for an app's developers to document how to convert a Web site URL to whatever input would be available to tell the app to go view something

So, what you want *may* be possible for *some* news apps, but the details would vary by app.

Comment: Got it. Well I guess that's a bummer. I mainly wanted to implement this so as to be able to save those articles in the app for future reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of - though this is an interesting concept.

**Here are some things to know:**

- the twitter app doesn't care how the intent is resolved. the purpose of the intent is to share external data. once the twitter app has handed over the intent with the url it is up to the android system to decide which app can resolve.
- the NY Times app is capable of opening because of this feature: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

**Workaround:**

- Learn to develop your own Android ROM to modify the Android Open Source Project adding your logic for intent resolution, compile and get your new Android ROM ready for deploy, install ROM on phone, keep your fingers crossed the entire time.

Comment: I guess that's way too much work for not that important of a work. Thanks for the reply!